# как сделать два равноразмерных квадратных блока?

Tags: css, css3, html5

Мне нужно сделать два равноразмерных квадратных блока
именно квадратных, и по длине и по ширине всегда равны!

Вот что я должен сделать:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

На данный момент я имею видео заголовок и эти два блока я сделал как колоны, оно респонсивно но у меня не получается сделать эти квадраты, на сколько я понимаю нужно использовать грид !

Мой код:

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    margin: 0;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

#bg {
    width: 100%;
}

.header {
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
    text-align: center;
    position:relative
}

#h-content {
    position: absolute;
    top:50%;
    left:50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.column {
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
    padding: 15px;
}

.row:after {
    content: "";
    display: table;
    clear: both;
}

p{
    text-indent: 30px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    .column {
        width: 100%;
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
    <div id="bg-container">
        <video id="bg" src="public/media/test.mp4" autoplay="true" loop="true" muted="true"></video>
    </div>
    <div id="h-content">
        <h1>Lorem ipsum dolor</h1>
    </div>

</div>

<div class="row">
    <div class="column">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum ut ex sapien. Fusce
            tempor leo leo, a dictum sem tincidunt vitae. Integer id lorem sit amet sapien dignissim
            ultrices. Nam porttitor posuere lorem, feugiat cursus diam finibus hendrerit.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="column">
        <h2>Column</h2>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas sit amet pretium urna. Vivamus venenatis
            velit nec neque ultricies, eget elementum magna tristique. Quisque vehicula, risus eget aliquam placerat,
            purus leo tincidunt eros, eget luctus quam orci in velit. Praesent scelerisque tortor sed accumsan
            convallis.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Собственно вот задача:

Для desktop: квадрат произвольного размера в центре экрана, состоящий из:

- прямоугольного блока с заголовком и видео на фоне;
- двух равноразмерных квадратных блоков: с заглушечным текстом и формой;
- футер с текстом произвольного размера внизу страницы.

Для мобильных устройств: 3 равноразмерных квадратных блока в полную ширину экрана и футер произвольного размера;

Answer (score 2):

Если просто квадратные резиновые блоки ...

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.item {
  width: 50vw;
  height: 50vw;
  background: red;
  margin: 30px auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="item"></div>
<div class="item"></div>
```